How to Configure WSO2 Choreo to Serve a config.js File for Environment Variables in a Vite + React App?
I am deploying a Vite + React application on WSO2 Choreo, and I use a config.js file to define runtime environment variables like this:

In my index.html, I reference this config.js file like this:
<script src="/config.js"></script>

This works perfectly in local development with local public/config.js file. However, after deploying to Choreo, I get the following error in the browser console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at config.js:1:1)
Additionally, when I try to access an environment variable like this:
const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_LOCAL_API_URL;
console.log("API URL:", apiUrl);

It shows undefined.
Then I tried creating environment variables as below,

Despite this setup, the variable is still showing as undefined.
How can I configure WSO2 Choreo to properly serve the config.js file or correctly inject environment variables into the React app? Are there additional steps required in Choreo to ensure this is working?
Any help would be appreciated.
